# Showing a set is closed and show a set is open(if and only if)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

[image]

To show $V$ is closed, I was thinking that showing that the complement is open (basically at this junction, the only ways I know how to show a set is closed is to either show that the complement is open or that the set contains all its limit points). I was thinking in this case showing the complement is open would be easier. I know that the span of $k$ vectors is geometrically in some $k$-dimensional space. I'm not really sure what the complement of this (to be honest) so obviously I'm confused and not sure if this is even the right way to think of the problem.

For part b), I think I know how to prove one direction but I'm not sure how to show that $V$ is open implies $V=\mathbb{R}^n$. Isn't this just true because only two sets are both open and closed, the empty set and the Mother space? Since $V$ is non-empty it must be $V=\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Do you know that all linear maps between finite-dimensional vector spaces are continuous?

Comment: I was not aware of this fact.  How can I use this fact to prove it is closed?

Comment: I do know preimages of open sets are open if a function is continuous

Comment: Preimages of closed sets are closed under a continuous function.

Comment: Makes sense.  How would I formalize this: V is closed because it is the set of preimages of closed sets in  a finite-dimensional dimensional vector space?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit lost, but trying to give an attempt.  Perhaps, my attempt didn't make sense.  Can you help me formalize this idea?  Thanks!!

Comment: You need to find some linear map which is going to be useful for this purpose. Then you can use the easy fact that $\{0\}$ is closed in any vector space.

Comment: This is starting to make more sense.  What is the process of finding a linear map.  Not familiar.